# Make Model Year SKU API in Bigcommerce

Tags: bigcommerce

Is there any api for get all Year, Make, Model and skus from bigcommerce?

https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/{{store_hash}}/v3/catalog/products/{{prouct_id}}/skus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BigCommerce doesn't have YMM fields. If that data is stored in custom fields or something, it should be available through api or csv export.